# WPF Datepicker doesn't raise textinput events

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datepicker

I've made a custom datepicker control to allow input of short dates (ex. "010111", "01012011" or "01-01-2011")
Somehow the events won't get triggered.

```
Public Class DatePicker
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker

Private Sub DatePicker_PreviewTextInput(sender As Object, e As Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewTextInput
    If Me.Text.Length >= 6 Then
        Dim strInput As String = Me.Text.Trim
        Dim dtInput As Date = Nothing

        Select Case strInput.Length
            Case Is = 6
                dtInput = New Date(CInt(Mid(strInput, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(strInput, 3, 2)), CInt(Mid(strInput, 1, 2)))
            Case Is = 8
                dtInput = New Date(CInt(Mid(strInput, 5, 4)), CInt(Mid(strInput, 3, 2)), CInt(Mid(strInput, 1, 2)))
            Case Is >= 10
                dtInput = New Date(CInt(Mid(strInput, 7, 4)), CInt(Mid(strInput, 4, 2)), CInt(Mid(strInput, 1, 2)))
        End Select

        Me.SelectedDate = dtInput
    End If

    e.Handled = True
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Silly question but your class has the same name - are you definitely using this control? Btw you seem to have some flaws in your logic. For one thing you are looking at your text property but since this is preview input it will be before the input has been processed - before the new text is added. Also since you are just basing on length you will always get to 6 characters before you get to 8 so you will change the text - assuming it even parses.

Comment: Dear AndrewS, the class name is not a problem. I've indeed solved the logic by another approach. Thanxxx for your input. As you can notice i still miss some experience in WPF. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i resolved it a different way.

```
Public Class DatePicker
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker

Private Sub DatePicker_LostKeyboardFocus(sender As Object, e As Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.LostKeyboardFocus
    Dim dtInput As DateTime
    Dim strInput As String = Me.Text.Trim

    If DateTime.TryParse(strInput, dtInput) = True Then
        Me.SelectedDate = dtInput
    Else
        Select Case strInput.Length
            Case Is = 6
                If DateTime.TryParseExact(Me.Text, "d", New DateTimeFormatInfo() With {.ShortDatePattern = "ddMMyy"}, DateTimeStyles.None, dtInput) Then
                    Me.SelectedDate = dtInput
                End If
            Case Is = 8
                If DateTime.TryParseExact(Me.Text, "d", New DateTimeFormatInfo() With {.ShortDatePattern = "ddMMyyyy"}, DateTimeStyles.None, dtInput) Then
                    Me.SelectedDate = dtInput
                End If
            Case Is >= 10
                If DateTime.TryParseExact(Me.Text, "d", New DateTimeFormatInfo() With {.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"}, DateTimeStyles.None, dtInput) Then
                    Me.SelectedDate = dtInput
                End If
        End Select
    End If

    e.Handled = True
End Sub End Class
```

Comment: If you're going to go this route then why not pass in the format directly instead of passing "d" and creating a new DateTimeFormatInfo with the actual format you are trying to parse as the ShortDateFormat? Otherwise you're overriding the culture information that it would have used. i.e. DateTime.TryParseExact(Me.Text, "ddMMyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, dtInput)